# How can I extract the outline of a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, regex, pdf, pypdf

I wish to read the outline of a .pdf format paper. The expected output is a list of section titles like `['abstract', 'Introduction', ...]`, The section titles can be identified by the following characteristics: 1) bold and larger font size, 2) all nouns starting with capital letters, and 3) appearing immediately after a line break `\n`.

The solutions I have tried with includes:

[pypdf2](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/index.html) with `reader.outline`

```
reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader('path/to/my/pdf')
print(reader.outline)
```

[pymupdf](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with `doc.get_toc()`

```
doc = fitz.open('path/to/my/pdf')
toc = doc.get_toc()
```

However both give me empty list.
I am currently using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library to extract the section titles, but the results include additional information such as references and table contents.

```
import re
re.findall(r'(\[turnpage\]|\n)([A-Z][^.]*?)(\n[A-Z0-9][^\s]*?)', text)
```

For a clearer understanding of the results produced by the code, please refer to this [link](https://regex101.com/r/098nAh/1)

Comment: my guess is that both libraries try to read from the bookmarks section of the PDF. if there's no such thing, they will come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

If `reader.outline` by pypdf gives an empty result, there is no outline specified as metadata.

There can still be an outline specified as normal text. However, detecting / parsing that would require custom work on your side. You can use the text extraction as a basis:

https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```